# How do I solve the following example using Kmap?

Tags: boolean-algebra

I am trying to solve the SOP function: Em(0,1,2,6,8,9,10). Here's what I got in the table:

```
    C'D' C'D CD CD'
A'B' 1   1   0  1
A'B  0   0   0  1
AB   0   0   0  0
AB'  1   1   0  1
```

My output function is y = B'C'+A'CD'+AB'D'. Is it accurate? My confusion is primarily about the position AB'CD'. Do I group it with AB'C'D' or all positions at the corners that include positions A'B'C'D' & A'B'CD'?

Answer (score 1):

To simplify as much as possible, you always want to create as large as groups as possible.

So yes, use the expression $B'D'$ to cover all corners instead of using $AB'D'$

So, the ultimate expression is $B'C'+A'CD'+B'D'$ ... which is indeed a little simpler than what you got.